# How to decorate EF Core's DbContext

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core, decorator

I am trying to decorate DbContext using Scrutor library so I can inject some code into `SaveChanges()`.

My decorator looks like this:

```cs
public class DbContextDecorator : DbContext
{
  private readonly DbContext _context;

  public DbContextDecorator(DbContext context)
  {
    _context = context
  }

  public override int SaveChanges()
  {
    _context.SaveChanges();
    // some other code
  }
}
```

and I am using it like

```cs
builder.Services.Decorate(typeof(MyContext), typeof(DbContextDecorator));
```

However when I want to retrieve my decorated `MyContext` either in constructor or using `GetService<MyContext>()`, it just hangs forever, it looks like it's deadlocked or what.

I have also tried to change my decorator class to

```cs
public class DbContextDecorator<TContext> : DbContext where TContext : DbContext
{
  private readonly TContext _context;

  public DbContextDecorator(TContext context)
  {
    _context = context
  }
}
```

and decorated it like

```cs
builder.Services.Decorate(typeof(MyContext), typeof(DbContextDecorator<MyContext>));
```

but it's the same, this was just my false hope that I thought may work.

Am I doing something wrong or is it not possible to decorate DbContext this way and I would need to create interface for it?

Comment: I don't know Scrutor, but at first glance it takes a lot more initialization than what you show here. Also, it only seems useful if you have multiple context classes that you want to decorate. If so, a better (because not requiring 3rd-party libraries) alternative is to create a base context class with the `SaveChanges` override and derive your other contexts from it.

Comment: Scrutor is "kind of magic library" which adds decorating functionality to Microsoft's DI. This exact code works when instead of `DbContext` I use for example `ISomeRepository`, so I have confirmed library's functionality, I just cannot make it working for DbContext

Comment: Are you sure that Scrutor's decoration works with non-interfaces or non-abstract classes? Because DbContext is neither.